# text moving out of the element using transform rotate

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have twisted the text to a 270 degree angle. my problem is aligning it inside another div.

Here is the image before I twisted the text:

[image]

and this is my my code for that for this:

```
#infoside {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 41%;
}

#tabbings {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
#tab_panels {
    float: right;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #00ffff;
}

#client_info {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}


 <div id="infoside">
    <div id="tabbings">
        <div id="client_info" class="active_tabbing">
            <div id="text_here" style="width: 100px; height: 25%; text-align: center">
                 CLIENT INFO
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab_panels"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and when I add this class to the div with id **text_here** that will twist the text the image below will be the result

```
.twist_text {
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
```

[image]

How do I make this be inside the square?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, there is no JavaScript used here

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/govebogo/2/edit

Comment: @Mr.Alien OH!! I forgot. There is no javascript. I'm sorry. This is all CSS and HTML. Im sorry. What I mean is to implement the second screenshot with placing the text inside the box above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `transform-origin:0 0;` on your CSS to set the rotation axis on the top left of your div. By default, it is set at `50% 50%`, and you can set it to any value you like.

Comment: I would add that you should be aware of browser support and required prefixes when using this: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: i added transform-origin but not  with 0 0 values. Adjusted it and worked!! I implemented it with the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If i got it........
Try this

```
.twist_text {
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-35px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-35px) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-35px) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-35px) ;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-35px);
}
```

after that it will look like below
[image]

Comment: while this work, it may make more sense to set the element's `transform-origin`, because if he changes its dimensions you will have to change all the translates again.

Comment: with transform-origin we can just change the rotating point of element. but here we need to change the position on X axis.
only adding transform-origin element goes out from it's parent div.

Comment: Let me try this for a while..

Comment: @AbhineetVispute Well, the default transform-origin is 50% 50%, so we set it to 0 0 and it will rotate around the top left edge, making positioning much more maintainable.

Comment: @Kroltan You are right, this needed a transform-origin and it worked like a charm. Thanks guys.